# i3wm touchpad "touch" doesn't work

Tags: touchpad, i3-wm

I use i3 window manager, the problem is that touchpad doesn't work when I just "touch" it, it works only when I press it till a click.

Is there any way to configure that function?

PS: when logged in the gnome mode, it works like it should.

Answer (score 2):

Hey in case if you are still looking for an answer, I found this great explanation [here](https://cravencode.com/post/essentials/enable-tap-to-click-in-i3wm/)

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d && sudo tee <<'EOF' /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-touchpad.conf 1> /dev/null
 Section "InputClass"
         Identifier "touchpad"
         MatchIsTouchpad "on"
         Driver "libinput"
         Option "Tapping" "on"
 EndSection
   EOF
```

Comment: This is a great solution!!! Thank you. I did this on a DELL 15 3000 which mousepad clic stopped working when using i3wm. Now everything works pretty fine. Thanks