Enable touchpad clicks and gestures in i3wm in Ubuntu 24.04
To enable touchpad gestures in freshly installed i3wm in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, I followed this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1292164/947071
But after logging out, I no longer see the option i3 option! And if I choose Ubuntu, it opens with Wayland, which I don't prefer. By removing the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-touchpad.conf, it becomes ok again. Why is it happening? How can I resolve the touch issue in i3wm?
